Changing a chatroom's details doesn't reload the page
If the owner of a chatroom renames the room, changes its tags or description, or switches it to Gallery mode, the clients of users who are currently in the room will not reload (possibly due to the RoomNameChanged event not firing). I seem to recall the page reloading when this occurred prior to the chat backend upgrade. Timing a room out doesn't reload the page either, and the timeout message doesn't seem to appear if no message was provided (or when the timeout is cleared by setting its duration to zero seconds).

I've reproduced this in https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1774/discussion-between-starship-and-franck-dernoncourt by opening the access controls in a separate tab and changing the room to Gallery (and back, of course). It did not reload the tab I had the room open in.

For the devs, it may be worth investigating other actions that cause a room reload that're less easy to investigate. Off the top of my head, kick-muting comes to mind, as does approving an access request to a gallery room.

Great catch, thanks for the report. This is fixed now.
One of the bigger changes when migrating Chat to .NET Core was due to the fact that Chat was originally built using Linq-to-SQL (L2S) for database access. L2S isn't really a thing anymore, so we had to move things to use EF Core. For the most part, this was fairly painless, because they work in pretty similar ways. But one thing that works differently is change tracking.
I messed up badly when I re-implemented some of that functionality in the new version, and it broke detection of changes to room configuration. When something like the room name or its access levels change, the detection of those changes cause events like RoomNameChanged (which you mentioned) and AccessLevelChanged.
But because this detection was broken, those events weren't triggered, and thus your Chat didn't know it had to update things or reload the page.
